# Link in Javascript alert

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, alert

I want to put a link in a Javascript alert.

Is this possible? (I've searching for a solution, but I keep getting things about links that fire alerts!)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

AFAIK you can't do that with a normal javascript alert box.

Make a custom alert box and then make a link inside it.

Here is a nice one

[YUI: Dialog Alert Widget](http://blog.davglass.com/files/yui/widget_alert/)

Also a jQuery based one

[jQuery Impromptu](https://trentrichardson.com/examples/Impromptu/)

Comment: Come now ,Andrew, because it is obviously not jQuery, and just like in the Highlander, there can be only one.

Answer (score 3):

Nope. Only standard OS dialog boxes are available (alert, input, etc.), and none support embedded hyperlinks.

You can could a pop-up window that is styled to *look like* a dialog, but pop-up windows are likely to have various user blocks, etc. in place.

My advice is to use a an absolutely-positioned DIV with a high z-order centered on your page that *looks like* a dialog box and put whatever you want in it. Various UI toolkits like JQuery UI take the pain out of this.