# Insert a link in a message from an array

Tags: php

I have a button on a webpage which when clicked, displays a dialog (if the user is not logged in) telling them to log in, I want to add to this message that if they are not registered, they can click to take them to the registration form.

The line of code that displays the message is this:

```
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" <?php if ( $userdata->ID ){ echo 'onclick="document.ClaimListing.submit();"'; }else{ ?>onclick="alert('<?php echo $PPT->_e(array('ajax','1')); ?>');"<?php } ?> class="button green" rel="nofollow"><?php echo $PPT->_e(array('membership','8')); ?></a>
```

Its basically saying if user is not logged in then display the message (in another file) from the ajax array, message number 1 (need to log in message) else display the message from the membership array, message number 8 (claim listing message).

The line in the other file with the ajax array, message number 1 is:

```
    "ajax" => array(

    "1"                     => "You need to be logged in to claim your listing. Not registered?",
```

How can I add a link after Not Registered? because if I just try a normal a hyperlink, it breaks the page.

Thanks.

Comment: It's impossible to insert a link in a JS alert.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Link in Javascript alert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733410/link-in-javascript-alert)

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to insert a link in a simple Javascript alert box.

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733410/link-in-javascript-alert) can helps you.

Comment: Afraid not, both of the example links in that post do not work.
But if it is not possible, I will have a re-think.
Thanks.

Comment: But still, you can make a little search on google and easily find what he was talking about, [here](http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/#Examples)'s the one I would recommend you to use.