# Place link in var msg=""

Tags: javascript

I am using this code to detect chrome browser. I want to place a link around some anchor text to another website inside the var msg ="" but I do not know how to do this.

```
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
var msg = "<a href=\"http://www.website.com\" target=\"new\">anchor text</a>";
if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome')>-1){
alert(msg);
}
</script>
```

Comment: hmm. not sure your question is clear enough

Comment: What? You can't place a click-able link within an alert (it can only show text, not html).

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't put clickable links inside `alert()`s.

You can either use an [existing HTML-based dialog box package](http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/) (or roll your own; for example, by showing a `div` with the appropriate message), or directly navigate to the new URL using JavaScript.

```
   if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome')>-1){
       // will automatically redirect Chrome users.
       window.location.href = "http://www.website.com";
   }
```

*Edit*: removed alert() suggestion for the sake of a better web. And since this appears to be a duplicate, pulled a recommendation from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733410/link-in-javascript-alert) for the sake of the OP.

Comment: Please don't put links into *alert* boxes! You can't copy them on some systems. If you really want to show a dialog, a *confirm* dialog would be better suited (using *Yes* for redirecting).

Comment: I couldn't agree more.